# Keyboard Shortcuts in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I want a Ctrl+V hotkey shortcut in my form. I've tried some variants of the following, with no luck:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.V And e.Control = True Then
        TextBox1.Text = "AUTO"
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Have you set `KeyPreview` on the form to `True`?  Otherwise the control that has focus will eat the event before the form has a chance to see it.

Comment: Yes, I added it to the form loading event (MyBase.Load).

Comment: Oh haaaa. Third clean and build was the charm. I guess I'll be closing this. @BradleyUffner thanks for your help.

Comment: see above. Yes it fired/succeeded